# Regex for selecting all but HEX color values

Tags: regex

I can select all HEX color values with `#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}`

But how to select all but those HEX values? I want to perform replace-all to remove everything but those colors.

You can test it here http://regex101.com/r/jT5yA9/2

Comment: Do you mean everything else in that snippet apart from the values such as #333, including the attributes associated with the values?

Comment: `/#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}(?![0-9a-f])/gi`?

Comment: @Wrikken What do you expect your regex to match?

Comment: @Ultra, which values are you talking about?

Comment: If you -1 than write why. @shree.pat18 yes

Comment: @Ultra I downvoted because you're question is not clear enough yet. Why don't you answer my question? You should edit your question to add examples you don't want to match (and explain *why* these examples, i.e. the rules).

Comment: @sp00m it's all stated in question, if you dont understand please logoff and turn off computer or at least stop contributing on topics you dont get.

Comment: @sp00m: I was commenting on his original regex matching the `#add` in `#addByXls`. Mine would at least fix that matching, but apparently, it fell on deaf ears. It was a comment fixing another issue then the original question (hence, not an answer ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by grouping.

Regex:

```
.*(#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}).*
```

Is replaced with:

```
$1
```

As `$1` is first group `()` which is my match whole line is replaced with it.

Shortcoming here is taht regex itself ignores what is after match so it will miss any other occurances after first match but I cant live with that.